# Algorithm for undirected projective dependency parsing

Tags: algorithm, parsing

I am looking for an algorithm that will get an optimal projective undirected dependency parse.

Equivalently, I am asking: what algorithms exist for finding a Minimum/Maximum Spanning Tree on an ordered graph, such that the resulting structure is projective?  Given a totally ordered set of nodes (*S*,<), and a edge weight function *W*: *S* × *S* → ℝ,  is there a good algorithm for finding the optimal-weight spanning tree over this set of nodes, such that the resulting structure has the property that every sub-tree is contiguous in the ordering (for any subtree *T*, for all *t*,*s* in *T* there is no *r* not in *T* such that *t*<*r*<*s*)?

- Without the projectivity requirement, any classic MST algorithm will do (such as [Prim's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm), or [Kruskal's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm)).
- With the projectivity requirement, but for *directed* graphs/dependencies [Eisner's](https://cs.jhu.edu/~jason/papers/eisner.coling96.pdf) [algorithm](https://zoo.cs.yale.edu/classes/cs470/2014--15-fall/14f-lecnotes/lec35.html) (a faster version of Arc-factored Projective Parsing) is standard for getting the optimal directed projective dependency parse.

I am looking for a (probably [CYK](https://www.xarg.org/tools/cyk-algorithm/)-like) algorithm like Eisner's, but which will work on undirected dependency parsing. That is, an algorithm for finding the maximum projective spanning tree for undirected ordered graphs.

Comment: This question seems like a good match for [cs.se].

Comment: ah, I just did. it's here:  https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/121246/algorithm-for-undirected-projective-dependency-parsing